# Typing vector space Rn in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, letters, vector

I am a beginner in LaTeX. I have trouble typesetting *V = Rn*

My code is: `\textit{V} =  $\mathbb{R^n}$`, but it doesn't give me the *n*, that I want.

This is what I want:

[image]

Instead my output is :

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$V = \mathbb{R}^n$
\end{document}` gives desired result. You should show us a small but complete document, which produce in your question showed result! Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In other words, `\mathbb` should be used with capital letters only. So, move the superscript outside it, as @Zarko had suggested.

Comment: Unrelated, but `\textit` means "this is text, and I want it to be italicized".  If you want something to be italicized because it's math, then first make sure that it's inside the math environment `$`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping me out. Now I am ready to play with Latex :)

Comment: `\mathbb` only applies to R; V is a math variable. Therefore `$V=\mathbb{R}^n$`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in two respects:

1. `V` and the equals sign should be part of the formula
2. the exponent `n` should be outside of `\mathbb`

So

```
$V=\mathbb{R}^n$
```

would be the correct code.

Don't think to `$` as a way to obtain funny symbols: a *whole* math formula should be between `$...$`. Or even single symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, and note that $V$ is a very important vector space.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Placing the exponent outside the {} brackets will fix the issue

```
$\mathbb{R}^n$
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE! This was suggested in my (and other) comment about three years ago ...